# How inject javascript before the web page loading in Android Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, javascript-injection

Really need someone to help me out.

I am trying to inject the javascript into the web page before the page loaded in android webview.

I searched a lot and only found solution that injecting javascript after the page is already loaded. like this:http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/

Actually I need to inject something like:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (document.readyState == 'interactive') 
 {
   do something to call Android exposed JavascriptInterface
 }
};
```

I need to inject this before the page loading because i need to listen to some event before the page is fully loaded. for example: i need to know when the page is ready to be interactive so that i can turn off the progress bar.
(I also expose an JavascriptInterface in my Android code by `webview.addJavascriptInterface()`)

I am wondering whether there's a way to add javascript before the page is load. And will combine my javascript into that page.

Something like:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:some javascript");
webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
```

Seems not working.

Comment: the event you want to listen is happening on webpage or on native side?

Answer (score 0):

Create two activity files instead of one activity. In initial activity load your javascript and based on result navigate to your second activity in which you can load your content in it.

Comment: you mean two activities with two webviews?